# What object is an assigned approver stored in?

Tags: approval-process

I can't find the user reference in ProcessNode or any process related objects.
I want to do find/replace for a user leaving the company and re-assign their approval roles.

To clarify, I don't want pending requests, I want the person who would be assigned, were an approval to be launched. For example, if I use the id of a new user who was just add in the process in the screen below but there is no active approval, it returns null. What object contains this relationship?

Thanks.
[image]

Comment: a mystery that is very odd!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`ProcessInstanceWorkItem`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_processinstanceworkitem.htm):

> Represents a user’s pending approval request.

Sample query:

```
SELECT ActorId FROM ProcessInstanceWorkItem WHERE ProcessInstanceId = '...'
```

Comment: To clarify, I don't want pending requests, I want the person who would be assigned, were an approval to be launched.

Comment: To clarify, I don't want pending requests, I want the person who would be assigned, were an approval to be launched. For example, if I use the id of a new user who is in the process but there is no active approval, it returns null. I have edited my question to clarify it.

Comment: Still, no one knows!